# How to:If the label contains "Alumini" then add class to input

Tags: javascript

There will be multiple sections with .Ev2_PriceTypesRow and I want to run a script for each but I am having trouble with the selectors.
I want the script to say:
If the label for class "Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption" within class "Ev2_PriceTypesRow" contains the text "Alumni" then add class "alumni" to input with ID "P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Alumni</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Student</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Child</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Alumni Comp</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So basically I want to add a class to the input field that you can see in the code snippet if the label text contains "Alumni". The html is hard coded, i cannot directly edit the HTML b/c the code is automatically produced by the software so I will need to use JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried using .closest but was unsuccessful as I believe this climbs up the DOM.

```
$('label:contains("Alumni")').closest('input').addClass('alumni');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
$('label:contains("Alumni")').parent().next().find('input').addClass('alumni');
```

```js
$('label:contains("Alumni")').parent().next().find('input').addClass('alumni');
```

```css
.alumni {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Alumni</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Student</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Child</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesRow">
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeNameColumn">
                        <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblDesc_0" class="Ev2_PriceName BBFieldCaption">Alumni Comp</label>
                        <div>
                            <label for="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" class="Ev2_PriceCount">1 registrant</label>
                            <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$ctl01" type="hidden" value="1" unit="10181" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeQtyColumn">
                        <input name="P1212$ev2wiz$step1$rptevts$ctl00$ctlevt$rptPrice$ctl00$txtQty" type="text" id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_txtQty_0" maxlength="2" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onmouseup="javascript:if(event &amp;&amp; event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}else{return false;}" value="0" buddy="10181" going="3660" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceItem_0" class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeAmountColumn" style="display:none">
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_lblPrice_0">$0.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ev2_PriceTypesCell Ev2_PriceTypeValidatorColumn">
                        <div id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_divPriceDescription_0" class="Ev2_PriceDescriptionCell"></div>
                        <span id="P1212_ev2wiz_step1_rptevts_ctlevt_0_rptPrice_0_ctl02_0" class="Ev2_Step1QtyValidation" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a whole number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```